# 'Updating Build Policies from *.java' error

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, eclipse-neon

Please help with the following error. It shows when trying to save changes on Eclipse Neon:

> 'Updating Build Policies from *.java' has encountered a problem.
>   An internal error occurred during: "Updating Build Policies from *.java"

In the details this is shown:

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Build Policies from *.java".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried to delete the project and import it again, but it happens again and doesn't depend on the project.

This is what I've got from .log from .metadata directory in the workspace

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-06-22 21:50:29.320
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Updating Build Policies from *.java".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.TypeVector.contains(TypeVector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.contains(TypeHierarchy.java:328)
    at org.gw4e.eclipse.facade.JDTManager.isGraphWalkerExecutionContextClass(JDTManager.java:779)
    at org.gw4e.eclipse.facade.ResourceManager$4.runInWorkspace(ResourceManager.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Comment: Please add more details to the error you are getting so others can help better

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed message. Edit your question to include the full message.

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449. I've added the .log info in my question.

Comment: And on second reading I saw why this error appeared - because of the GraphWalker plugin I've installed.